# How can i make the user to give the right value?

Tags: c#

The problem is that the courselist[y] works only for 0 value or 1 if i add a second courselist.How i can obligate the user to give the right value?
Also if the courselist is empty , what i have to do to show the appropiate message?

```
    public static void AddTrainer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Trainer name");
        string sname = Console.ReadLine();
        Trainer tr = new Trainer(Helper.trainerlist.Count() + 1, sname);
        Helper.trainerlist.Add(tr);
        Console.WriteLine("Give course");
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        //y = y - 1;
        Helper.courselist[y].trainerIDlist.Add(Helper.trainerlist.Count());
        Helper.ShowMenu2();
    }
```

Comment: Do you want the user to input only 0 or 1?

Comment: `bool incorrectValue = !int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int y) || y >= Helper.courselist.Count;`.

Comment: What is your UI... WinForms, WPF, etc.  As for what asking for input, can you EDIT your existing post and show simple example of your "Courses" and context of having multiple course lists?  The existing courselist would imply multiple courses and you could get a value within any ordinal index within the courselist.Count().

Answer (score 0):

You could ask again until the user provides the correct value

```
string input;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Give course (0 or 1)");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}
while (input != "0" && input != "1");

int y = Convert.ToInt32(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("Give course");
int y;

while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out y) || y >= Helper.courselist.Count() || y < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Give course that already created (1,2,3,...etc)");
}

Helper.courselist[y].trainerIDlist.Add(Helper.trainerlist.Count());
```

This worked , but i want to give 1 for the first courselist , not 0. And what if the courselist is empty?